# LWUIT bitmap-font not working done?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, bitmap-fonts

When I use a bitmap font in lwuit `List` in emulator and SonyEricsson k510i everythings right but in g900 if font size is bigger than 9 words, is not shown ? please help me to fix this problem ...

Answer (score 0):

When using bitmap font, you have to use different font objects for different screen width.

For Example, if the font size for 240*320 device is 12 means, set font size to 20 for 360*640.

No other solution is available to solve this issue.